# Generating test data for Sitecore Analytics

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I need to test Sitecore Analytics. Someone have any idea or tip how can I configure and generate fake data in Sitecore Analytics? Because only one person acessing the pages or campaigns, I cannot see any result in the reports.

Comment: I haven`t tested myself but have you tried this KB article?
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/398589

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Sitecore XGenerator for generating analytics data. More information you can find on [Sitecore Github Repository](https://github.com/Sitecore/xGenerator)

**Experience Generator**

Generate "realistically looking" traffic for the Sitecore Experience Database (xDB) with configurable patterns, including:

Trends over time

Identified contacts with multiple visits

Bounce rate

Geo location

Landing pages

Channels

Referrers

Internal and external search

Outcomes

Campaigns

**Experience Profile Generator**

Generate visits for Sitecore contacts (xProfile) with configurable settings:

Contact information

Visit pages

Recency

Outcomes

Geo location

Goals

Channel

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter to do the work for you. [Here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/398589) is how to set this. You would need

- JRE6 or Later
- Apache Jmeter
- [RandomWalk Script](https://bitbucket.org/scSPL/jmeter-randomwalk)
- Properly configured xDB